# Access secrets manager from running task in ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I have ecs that is running in a vpc and i want to access a secret that is in secrets manager. I can give secret as environment variable while creating task but i want to read it in container because this secret will be rotated. I opened secrets manager endpoint for my vpc. How can i access it?

Edit:

I tried accesing by using this code. This is called when i send a get request to ecs instance.

```
        secretName := os.Getenv("SECRET_NAME")
        region := os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")
        sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

        svc := secretsmanager.New(sess, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion(region))

        result, err := svc.GetSecretValue(&secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{SecretId: &secretName})
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", gjson.Get(*result.SecretString, "test_secrets"))
```

Edit 2:

[cloudwatch log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uboq2.png) Error happens when i send a request to endpoint that runs above code to access secret manager.

Note: ECS instance is accessed through a load balancer and i tested other endpoints and it works.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you facing? If you set up the VPC endpoints and the proper IAM permissions it should just work.

Comment: Have you written any code to do this yet? What programming language are you using?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @luk2302 I couldn't find any propoer guide about doing this so tried doing this by using aws-sdk for go but i think the permissions and vpc endpoints are setup right since i can access secrets while creating task

Comment: So you have added your code to the question, but you haven't specified where you are stuck. Is the code not working? Are you getting an error? Please edit your question to include details of the problem.

Comment: I added the cloudwatch log but i don't think it gives too much info also. As i understand aws-sdk initiliazes itself by using credentials from environment variables i didn't pass credentials to task maybe it failed because of this.

Comment: If you are using task roles, make sure you are giving the permission in the Task Role and not the Task execution role, the first one gives permissions to your task to other AWS APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Okey i found the problem endpoint security group didn't allow port 443 this solved my problem reference:https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-secrets-manager-issues/